# Disable TestNG Listeners

Tags: testng

I am currently creating TestNG test cases for a big project with a lot of modules. Most of the unit tests that are existing are actually Integration Tests as they rely a lot on configuration files located in the /opt folder as well as running database and message queues.

To complicate things further the test case use TestNG Listeners with the configuration located in the resources/META-INF/services/org.testng.ITestNGListener file. The listeners in this file fire for all the test cases (as expected).

Is there a way I can disable the listeners from firing for some of the test classes? I already tried annotating the test class with @Listener({}) to indicate that no listeners will be used but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, it's not possible to remove listeners defined via service locator.
If you really need it, you can ask the feature and/or try to propose a pull-request: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues

For your information, it will be possible to remove listeners from `@Listeners` in the next release of TestNG: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/900